# Passing user input in link_to params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-input

I am trying to pass an user input into link_to params. I know generally you use forms but here I am not linking these params to a particular model so I just want to access the user input and then pass it to params when user clicks on the link.

Something like this:

```
Ask for user input - <div><%= date_field :date%></div>
```

Then pass it in params -

```
<td><%= link_to "Send", controller_func_path(date: 'date_field value') %></td>
```

Comment: "but here I am not linking these params to a particular model" - not relevant, you still should use form, with `GET` method. It's possible.

Comment: "Ask for user input... Then pass it in params" - this represents a fundamental misunderstanding of the temporal sequence of events. `link_to` is rendered before the page is presented for user input. So, you can't "pass an user input into link_to params".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to link the form to a model to send input data. You can use the form to send the input data as follows:

**foo.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with url: boo_action_path do |form| %>
 <%= form.text_field :foo %>
 <%= form.submit 'Send' %>
<% end %>
```

**foo_controller.rb**

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def boo
    foo_input_value = params[:foo]
  end
end
```

Comment: @Sumitsharma You are welcome. Can you mark my answer as an answer and upvote it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Demir is right, sending data with normal forms is more practical. However, if changing links on the fly is a strict requirement, you can do so with javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function changeLink() {
    date = document.getElementById('date_changeable').value;
    targetHref = document.getElementById('tochange')
    baseLink = targetHref.dataset.baseLink
    document.getElementById('tochange').href = baseLink + date;
  }
</script>

<%= date_field 'date', 'changeable', onchange: 'changeLink()' %>

<td><%= link_to "Send", 'http://example.com', data: { base_link: 'http://example.com' + '/' }, id: 'tochange' %></td>
```